# Custom AJAX form not working async

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I have a contact from that uses PHP mailer that I have integrated into my Wordpress blog. The script sends emails no problem - the issue is that it does not work async so once the form is submitted I am taken to another page with the following text on it: `{"message":"Your message was successfully submitted from PHP."}`. The script works as expected when used outside of wordpress - I have no idea whats going on.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-8 site-block">
        <form id="form" method="post" class="form-horizontal ajax" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/php/process-contact.php" data-toggle="validator">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Enter your full name and title here" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input name="number" type="number" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Enter your preferred telephone number here" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Enter your preferred email address here" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputMessage" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <textarea name="description" class="form-control" id="inputMessage" placeholder="Type your message here" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <button id="submit-email" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
                  <div id="feedbackSubmit"></div>

      </div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

  /**
   * Sets error header and json error message response.
   *
   * @param  String $messsage error message of response
   * @return void
   */
  function errorResponse ($messsage) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    die(json_encode(array('message' => $messsage)));
  }
  /**
   * Pulls posted values for all fields in $fields_req array.
   * If a required field does not have a value, an error response is given.
   */
  function constructMessageBody () {
    $fields_req =  array("name" => true, "description" => true, "email" => true, "number" => true);
    $message_body = "";
    foreach ($fields_req as $name => $required) {
      $postedValue = $_POST[$name];
      if ($required && empty($postedValue)) {
        errorResponse("$name is empty.");
      } else {
        $message_body .= ucfirst($name) . ":  " . $postedValue . "\n";
      }
    }
    return $message_body;
  }


//header('Content-type: application/json');


//attempt to send email
$messageBody = constructMessageBody();
require 'php_mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->addAddress("example@example.com");
$mail->Subject = $_POST['name'];
$mail->Body  = $messageBody;
//try to send the message
if($mail->send()) {
  echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Your message was successfully submitted from PHP.'));
} else {
  errorResponse('An expected error occured while attempting to send the email: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
}

 ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function($) {

  $('#form').on('submit', function(){
    event.preventDefault();  

    var contactFormUtils = {
      clearForm: function () {
        grecaptcha.reset();
      },
      addAjaxMessage: function(msg, isError) {
        $("#feedbackSubmit").append('<div id="emailAlert" class="alert alert-' + (isError ? 'danger' : 'success') + '" style="margin-top: 5px;">' + $('<div/>').text(msg).html() + '</div>');
      }
    };


    $('#submit-email').prop('disabled', true).html("sending");

      var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

      that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
        var that = $(this),
        name = that.attr('name'),
        value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;

      });

      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: type,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
          console.log('success');
          $('#form').fadeOut(400)
          contactFormUtils.addAjaxMessage(data.message, false);
          contactFormUtils.clearForm();

        },
        error: function(response) {
          console.log('error');
          contactFormUtils.addAjaxMessage(response.responseJSON.message, true);
          $('#submit-report').prop('disabled', false).html("Send message");
          contactFormUtils.clearForm();

        },
        complete: function() {
          console.log('complete');

        }
      });

    return false;
  });
})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

First probable issue: You're using `name` in the form. You should not, since it's a [reserved term](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) in WordPress.

Second probable issue: You're using a form action URL of `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/php/process-contact.php`. That will break if you use any WordPress functions (or functions defined in `functions.php` and plugins). [This is the correct way](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to implement AJAX in WordPress.